# Change the ios app submission release date modify later to "Hold for Developer Release"

Tags: ios

I have submitted the ios app to App store with release date. Currently, App in "Waiting for review". Later i have decided to modify to "Hold for Developer Release".

How do i achieve to change the release date to "Hold for Developer Release"?

Answer (score 5):

One other thing to note, you can only "Hold for Developer Release" when submitting *updates* to your app, it's not an option for the first upload of a new app.

> EDIT - I believe this is now supported in iTunes connect.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the availability date in the pricing section in iTunes connect.

As far as I can tell looking at the iTunes Connect documentation this is correct, but I'm not 100% sure.

I've emailed Apple on the issue... I'm in the same boat at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the release date to some far-in-the-future date. I use my planned release date, but one year forward (i.e. 2014 for a planned 2013 release, which just makes it slightly easier to change to the real date when it's approved)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the availability date of your app in the "**Rights and pricing**" in the Manage Your Application part of the iTunesConnect site